# AWS CloudSearch - How to know if the documents submitted were successfully indexed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Let's say I upload 10,000 documents to CloudSearch. CloudSearch would take some time to index them and I already have another 10,000 documents lined up to be uploaded. Now, the problem is that my ingestion flow would check if any of the documents in second batch already exists in my domain. If it does, then it would merge these documents and then upload them. However, if the indexing is in progress then my ingestion flow might miss some records and they will be overwritten by the second batch.

How can I solve this problem?

Can I know if the first batch has finished indexing before I start ingestion of the second batch?

Comment: Hey, just wondering if you know if AWS implemented a way to inspect indexing? My usecase is that I am inserting some data into cloudsearch for integration testing before my tests, and poll to see if I have that data available. I want to see if I can optimize this since it takes a long time to poll (~20 seconds).